# Find Substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have to find substring as follows.

Data as below

---

```
aaaa.bbb.ccc.dddd.eee.fff.ggg 

qq.eeddde.rrr.t.hh.jj.jj.hh.hh 

ee.r.t.y.u.i.ii.
```

I want output as-

---

```
bbb

eeeddde

r
```

---

challenge I am facing is all have (.) as separator so sub-string is tough to work.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string,CHARINDEX('.',string)+1,
       (((LEN(string))-CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(string)))-CHARINDEX('.',string))) AS Result 
  FROM [table]
```

---

```
bbb

eeeddde

r
```

---

looking substring between first and secound (.)

then it might be between second and third (.)

Comment: Please tag your dbms

Comment: How do you know if it is between the 1st and 2nd dot or between the 3rd and 4th?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select left(v.str1, charindex('.', v.str1 + '.') - 1)
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.string, 1, charindex('.', t.string + '.'), '')
     ) v(str1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume (CHARINDEX) this is ms sql server.
`CROSS APPLY` is handy for intermediate calculations.

```
SELECT t.pos, t1.pos,
  SUBSTRING(string, t.pos + 1, t1.pos - t.pos -1) AS Result 
FROM [table]
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',string)) ) t(pos) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',string, t.pos+1))) t1(pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option is to use a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeColumn varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'aaaa.bbb.ccc.dddd.eee.fff.ggg')
,(2,'qq.eeddde.rrr.t.hh.jj.jj.hh.hh')
,(3,'ee.r.t.y.u.i.ii.')


Select ID
      ,SomeValue = convert(xml,'<x>' + replace(SomeColumn,'.','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeValue
1   bbb
2   eeddde
3   r
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left()`, `replace()` and `charindex()` functions together :

```
select replace(
        replace(
               left(str,charindex('.',str,charindex('.',str)+1)),
               left(str,charindex('.',str)),
               ''
               ),
               '.'
               ,''
              ) as "Output"
  from t;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=967c51777d0fb56c41974e1e6aeb0986)</kbd>

Comment: In case I have to find out string between, 2 and 3rd , what should I do ?

Comment: @Andrew consider two step [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32923911728763b716f062c9351e8a85) in that case.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros. Not able to figure this out. I have column name put in str but no luck.

Comment: and what will be best to do in case I have to find sub string between 4 and 5th .. things are getting complicated. I have to update another based on some character are present in the 3rd and 4th (.). in future it might be between 4th and 5th (.).  Any other simple solution you have in your mind will be helpful

Comment: Hi @Andrew. As an Oracle man I also feel the lack of some regex operations throughout SQL Server. In such type of questions we mostly use `charindex()`which has no `occurence` argument. For this reason, extracting a substring process mostly depends on hard-coding unfortunately. If your strings had two or three dots, you would be able to use `parsename()` function to extract the desired substring easily.